# when we hit the open url using karate getting unknown host exception error?

Tags: junit, karate

**Featurefile**:

**Scenario**: sanitys API
Given url 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
When method get
Then status 200

Getting the below exception `java.net.UnknownHostException`.

`Response:[31mjavax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.UnknownHostException: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
        at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.method(StepDefs.java:318)
        at ✽.When method get(Feature/get.feature:13)
      Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:399)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
        at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.method(StepDefs.java:318)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
        at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
        at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.runChild(Karate.java:60)
        at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.runChild(Karate.java:25)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.run(Karate.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
      [0m
    [36mThen [0m[36mstatus [0m[36m[1m200[0m                                          [90m# StepDefs.status(int)[0m`

Comment: Could anyone please help on resolving this issue?

Comment: yes, please make sure you are connected to the internet, confirm that you can ping `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are connected to the internet, confirm that you can ping `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` and try again.